# How can I tell if I'm including google analytics twice?

Tags: analytics

I have a web app and I include google analytics. My active users seems to of spiked and I'm incredibly paranoid that I'm somehow double counting my analytics.

Is there any way to see if I'm doing this?

Answer (score 1):

- As Nebojsa mentioned, you can inspect source and search for `ga.js` or `analytics.js` to see if it's in your application twice.
- Look through your source code to see if you have the partial rendering in multiple places (ex. header and footer)
- Setup another Google Analytics account and test locally if its double counting your visits. See this [post for setting up GA on localhost](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19943786%2Fgoogle-universal-analytics-localhost-setup&ei=eqDFU9zoJoHIsATKpIHQAQ&usg=AFQjCNFKy27x4oxO7YFCjL9djgakoOZx4g&sig2=I5gDYw3q6scdUE7n7SRjiQ&bvm=bv.70810081,d.b2U)
- Use the [Google Analytics Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) to verify that everything is setup correctly. It will tell you if there are any implementation problems, including multiple tracking codes. It also helps with Adwords, re-marketing and other Google product scripts.
- Use the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en). This would probably be the most helpful to determine if a single hit is being double counted as it walks you though every single function call the analytics urchin makes.

Answer (score 0):

just open source in the browser and look-up for code of analitics...par example

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', ...
```